# Dictate a list of items in the presence of background noise

Tags: android, speech-recognition, user-experience, speech-to-text

I'm looking for a nice way to build a feature in my Shopping List App that allows the user to dictate the shopping list.

What I've done so far is what follows:

- I added a "record" button.
- When the button is pressed the user is prompted to dictate an item to add (and the button becomes red to indicate that the registration is started).
- If the user spells an item correctly, the item is added to the list. Then the user is prompted to dictate another item.
- If the user doesn't spell correctly or there's an error in the recognition, the dictation is interrupted (and the "record" button goes back to black).

The main problems with this solution are:

- If there's a background noise, like other people talking, incorrect items are added.
- If you say something while adding products, those words are added.

Someone suggested that the user should press the record button each time he wants to add a product, but that would be a little bothering.

Comment: Overall, speech recognition applications are complex to design and build, modern algorithms do not perform well in the presence of external speech. One possible solution would be to use an activation keyword like "create list" similar to "ok google". You can use pocketsphinx on android to listen for keyword locally as in http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid or you can implement a custom solution. Activation algorithms specifically designed to work in noise.